# Buildfile for Java with external jars

Tags: java, windows, ant, command-line, jar

I have tried and tried again to develop an Ant Buildfile for my project outline here:

[NoClassDefFoundError when running Java from Windows command line with external jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397952/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-java-from-windows-command-line-with-external-j)

This is the Buildfile I have tried to run:

```
<project>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

    <path id="jarpath">
        <fileset dir="C:\JAR">
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath id="jarpath" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="jarpath" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
        <jar destfile="build/jar/TestCase1.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="NSSR.TestCase1" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/UniversalVariables.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="NSSR.UniversalVariables" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

When I put "ant compile" into the command line in Windows, it gives me this behemoth of an error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Case
s\src\build.xml

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\wor
kspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cases\src\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:3: package com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:4: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.After;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:5: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.Before;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:6: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.Test;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:10: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class SeleneseTestCase
    [javac] public class TestCase1 extends SeleneseTestCase {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:3: package com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:4: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.After;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:5: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.Before;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:6: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.Test;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:10: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class SeleneseTestCase
    [javac] public class TestCase1 extends SeleneseTestCase {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Before
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]     @Before
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:30: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Test
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]     @Test
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:65: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class After
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]     @After
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Before
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]     @Before
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:30: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Test
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]     @Test
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:65: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class After
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]     @After
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:25: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*fire
fox",
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:25: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class DefaultSelenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*fire
fox",
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:27: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.start();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:32: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.open(UniversalVariables.loginPage);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:33: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("name=USERNAME", UniversalVariables.userna
me);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:34: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("name=PASSWORD", UniversalVariables.passwo
rd);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:35: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Submit");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:37: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.open("/itg/dashboard/app/portal/PageView.jsp?IS
_WINDOID=N");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:38: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Create");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:39: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Request");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:40: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:41: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.select("name=REQUEST_TYPE_CREATE",
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:43: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("css=span.secBtn > a");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:44: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:55: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("id=REQ.DESCRIPTION", title);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:56: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("id=REQ.P.REQUESTORAC_TF", req);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:57: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.select("id=REQ.P.REQUESTOR_DEPT", dept);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:58: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("id=REQ.P.DETAIL_DESC", desc);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:59: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("REQ.P.REQ_COMPL_DATE", date);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:60: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Submit");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:61: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.refresh();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\NSSR\TestCase1.java:67: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class NSSR.TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.stop();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:25: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*fire
fox",
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:25: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class DefaultSelenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*fire
fox",
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:27: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.start();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:32: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.open(UniversalVariables.loginPage);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:33: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("name=USERNAME", UniversalVariables.userna
me);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:34: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("name=PASSWORD", UniversalVariables.passwo
rd);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:35: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Submit");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:37: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.open("/itg/dashboard/app/portal/PageView.jsp?IS
_WINDOID=N");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:38: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Create");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:39: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Request");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:40: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:41: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.select("name=REQUEST_TYPE_CREATE",
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:43: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("css=span.secBtn > a");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:44: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:55: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("id=REQ.DESCRIPTION", title);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:56: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("id=REQ.P.REQUESTORAC_TF", req);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:57: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.select("id=REQ.P.REQUESTOR_DEPT", dept);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:58: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("id=REQ.P.DETAIL_DESC", desc);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:59: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.type("REQ.P.REQ_COMPL_DATE", date);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:60: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.click("link=Submit");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:61: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.refresh();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cas
es\src\TestCase1.java:67: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable selenium
    [javac] location: class TestCase1
    [javac]             selenium.stop();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] 64 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cases\src\build
.xml:15: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

Basically put, it doesn't appear to recognize anything from my jar files, which I suppose makes sense given that I don't reference them in the compile target.  The problem is that I don't know *how* to reference them (this is my first Buildfile apart from my Hello World).

Thank you

Comment: Try changing C:\JAR to C:\\JAR or C:/JAR

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is setting up and managing the classpath. This is by far the most common problem with ANT builds...

When I reviewed your code it looks like you should be running junit...

I put together a revised build file that demonstrates the following:

1. Uses [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage all 3rd party jar dependencies
2. Running junit tests using the ant [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)
3. Packaging an executable jar complete with classpath

Hope it helps.

## Example

The project has been built from source provided in the following question:

[NoClassDefFoundError when running Java from Windows command line with external jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397952/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-java-from-windows-command-line-with-external-j)

```
|-- build.xml
`-- src
    `-- NSSR
        |-- TestCase1.java
        `-- UniversalVariables.java
```

You'll need to run the following target once to install the [ivy plugin](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)

```
ant bootstrap
```

Build is then run as follows

```
ant clean jar
```

The generated jar can then be executed as follows;

```
java -jar build/dist/demo.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="jar" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <!--
    ==========
    Properties
    ==========
    -->
    <property name="src.dir"     location="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   location="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="dist.dir"    location="${build.dir}/dist"/>

    <property name="jar.file"       location="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    <property name="jar.main.class" value="NSSR.TestCase1"/>

    <property name="javac.deprecation" value="false"/>
    <property name="junit.haltonfailure" value="false"/>

    <!--
    =======
    Targets
    =======
    -->
    <target name="bootstrap" description="Install ivy">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get src="https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&amp;g=org.apache.ivy&amp;a=ivy&amp;v=LATEST&amp;e=jar"
             dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init" description="Resolve dependencies and set classpaths">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="default">
            <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium" rev="2.0rc2"/>
            <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.10"/>
        </ivy:cachepath>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the code">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" classpathref="build.path"/>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="compile" description="Run unit tests">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/tests"/>

        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="${junit.haltonfailure}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="build.path"/>
                <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${build.dir}/tests">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*Test*.java"/>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="test" description="Build jar files">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>

        <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${jar.file}">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </manifestclasspath>

        <jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${jar.main.class}" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Remove build files">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
      <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <pathelement location="classes"/>
      <dirset dir="${build.dir}">
        <include name="apps/**/classes"/>
        <exclude name="apps/**/*Test*"/>
      </dirset>
      <filelist refid="third-party_jars"/>
    </classpath>
```

See [Writing a simple build file](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

Comment: When I run that replacing "${build.dir}" with ".", I get this error:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\jradcliffe\workspace\ITSM_Upgrade_Test_Cases\src\build
.xml:15: Reference third-party_jars not found.

Comment: the **third-party_jars** is an example, you can delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `compile` target such that within `<javac>` the `<classpath>` uses `refid` instead of `id` as follows:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <javac srcdir="." destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="jarpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```